# Move Leaflet.TimeDimension plugin slider with keyboard?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I added a time dimension slider to a leaflet map to display a series of points in a range of time. This is the code:

```
     var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
        zoom: 3,
        center: [50.4, 10.7],
        keyboard: false,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionOptions: {
          timeInterval:  startDate + "/" + endDate ,
          period: "P30D"
        },
      });  


      var timeDimension = mymap.timeDimension;
      var player        = new L.TimeDimension.Player({
        transitionTime: 100,
        loop: false,
        startOver:true
      }, timeDimension);
    
      var timeDimensionControlOptions = {
          player:        player,
          timeDimension: timeDimension,
          position:      'bottomleft',
          autoPlay:      false,
          minSpeed:      1,
          speedStep:     0.5,
          maxSpeed:      15,
          timeSliderDragUpdate: true
      };
    
      var timeDimensionControl = new L.Control.TimeDimension(timeDimensionControlOptions);
      mymap.addControl(timeDimensionControl);
    
      L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(myjsonlayer,{
          updateTimeDimension: true,
          addlastPoint: true,
          waitForReady: true
      }).addTo(mymap);
```

I would like to move the sliderbar cursor also with keyboard arrow keys as well as mouse or play button.
Is there a way to do this?
This is an example of my map.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Leaflet.TimeDimension` plugin has no native keyboard support, you have to catch keyboard events with standard `keydown` event listener and then use plugin `.nextTime` and `.previousTime` methods to move the slider.

Code for this could look something like this:

```
function handleKeyDown(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 39)
    timeDimension.nextTime(1);
  else if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
    timeDimension.previousTime(1);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
```